# PHP - Boolean reply not working as expected

Tags: php, boolean

I have the following;

```
 (bool)$is_sent = $this->send_contact($message_name);
```

What above should do is return TRUE if the email is sent and the error message if the email is not sent.  So I have written this:

```
$this->send_contact() {
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        return $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        return TRUE; // success
    }
}
```

If I dump $is_sent when the message is successful it returns 1 as expected.  If I dump $is_sent when there is an error I see the error message.

I have the following next:

```
 if (
     ($this->MH_contact_model->contact_create($submitted_data) !== FALSE)  
     && 
     ($is_sent ==  TRUE)  ) 
 {  do_something(); }
```

The problem is that in both cases $is_sent somehow always evaluates to true but when I echo it to screen it contains the error message.  I need it to be FALSE or not TRUE.

How should I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `return $mail->send() ? true : false` ?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. You will find your mistake yourself, I'm sure. Also, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The problem with return $mail->send() ? true : false is that I don't get $mail->ErrorInfo on FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that a non-empty string is considered true in a boolean context (see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)), so `$is_sent == TRUE` is always true. You need to use a strict comparison instead:

```
($is_sent === TRUE)
```